# Section title in header problem

Tags: sectioning

My problem is that my section titles in header overlap with the chapter title.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fullpage]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\section{Ιστορικά στοιχεία}

\subsection{Τεχνολογία ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης  και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής.}

\subsection{Αρχικός σχεδιασμός}

\par{\lettrine[lines=2]{Ο}{όρος} της τεχνολογίας ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής ή αλλιώς \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} προσδιορίζει τη συνεργασία ανάμεσα σε ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD} και ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAM} προκειμένου το πρώτο να καθοδηγήσει μια εργαλειομηχανή ηλεκτρονικά ώστε να κατασκευάσει το ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο\index{ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο}. Για το οδοντιατρικό σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} τα δεδομένα προκύπτουν από μια κάμερα ή έναν παντογράφο\index{παντογράφος} ή μια οποιοδήποτε άλλη συσκευή που ψηφιοποιεί τα δεδομένα που προκύπτουν από το στόμα του ασθενή. Στη συνέχεια ο οδοντίατρος επεξεργάζεται τα δεδομένα σε μια οθόνη και με τη βοήθεια ενός λογισμικού μπορεί να κατασκευάσει ψηφιακά την οδοντιατρική αποκατάσταση, η οποία στη συνέχεια κατασκευάζεται σε ένα κοπτικό μηχάνημα το οποίο είναι είτε μια ξεχωριστή μονάδα ανεξάρτητη από την κάμερα ή την συσκευή ψηφιοποίησης και του επεξεργαστή δεδομένων, είτε αποτελεί ένα ενιαίο τμήμα των παραπάνω. Σχηματικά ο τρόπος λειτουργίας του συστήματος \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} φαίνεται στο παρακάτω σχήμα.}
\section{Στεφάνες στη νεογιλή οδοντοφυΐα.

Με την πρόοδο της οδοντιατρικής πρόληψης, τη χρήση φθοριούχων σκευασμάτων καθώς και το εισαγωγή του φθορίου στο πόσιμο νερό, ο επιπολασμός της τερηδόνας στην παιδική ηλικία έχει μειωθεί []. Παρόλα αυτά, υπάρχουν περιστατικά με βαριά τερηδονισμένα νεογιλά δόντια που πρέπει να αντιμετωπισθούν με πολφοτομή και την τοποθέτηση στεφανών. Η διατήρηση των νεογιλών δοντιών σε καλή κατάσταση στη στοματική κοιλότητα είναι βασική για την εξασφάλιση της γενικής υγείας, την εξασφάλιση της σωστής μασητικής λειτουργίας αλλά και την διατήρηση του χώρου για την ανατολή στις σωστές θέσεις των μόνιμων διάδοχών τους. Η μη διατήρηση των νεογιλών δοντιών και η πρώιμη εξαγωγή τους συνοδεύεται από μια σειρά ανεπιθύμητων καταστάσεων όπως είναι ο εγκλεισμός των μόνιμων δοντιών, διάφορες στοματογναθολογικές παθολογικές καταστάσεις, κακή στοματική αισθητική, ψυχολογικά προβλήματα για το παιδί.

\selectlanguage{english}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}
\printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]

\selectlanguage{greek}
\printindex
\newpage
\selectlanguage{greek}
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make an MWE that really reproduces your problem. In your code, except the lack of a `}` and some commands undefined, I don't see your problem.

Comment: `\par{...}` looks very wrong, I would start by removing `\par` and the `{..}`  so `\lettrine` is not inside a group.

Comment: If the problem is simply the long titles in the heading you can use a shorter version for the heading and table of contents `\subsection[short version]{Τεχνολογία ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης  και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής.}`